# Access HoloLens depth image in Unity?

Tags: hololens

Does anyone know how to access the raw depth image from the Hololens depth camera in a Unity app?  I know that I have to enable "research mode" on the Hololens.  I have seen the example of "SensorStreamViewer" at https://github.com/Microsoft/HoloLensForCV/tree/master/Samples/SensorStreamViewer, but this is a DirectX app.  I would like to use Unity because it seems easier than DirectX for prototyping and development (especially for a new developer like me!).

Incidentally, I plan to stream the depth images to an external desktop PC for object recognition, and receive the results back on the Hololens so that I can render holograms aligned with the real object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After talking to numerous people, including Microsoft tech support, I have found out that you can only access the Hololens depth camera image if you enable research mode and then write C++ code and use DirectX.  It is not possible to access the depth camera using C# and Unity.

If someone else wants to pursue this, it may be possible to write C++ code that accesses the depth camera, and put that into a plugin dll that can be used from Unity. As an example, the following project shows how to access the webcam stream from within Unity (but not the depth camera): https://github.com/VulcanTechnologies/HoloLensCameraStream.

Answer (score 2):

Dont know If I understood it right. I would recommend to check the SpatialMappingExample and SpatialProcessing. Its about visualizing and accessing spatial mapping data. Processing the raw spatial mapping data, finding and creating planes based on spatial mapping meshes... But right now they deleted all the guides because of the new MRTK V2 -.- so I cant give you reference

Even the [references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/spatial-mapping-in-unity) on the microsoft documentation (on the bottom) are referencing to a not exisiting page

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I should have mentioned that I am also using the RGB color camera, and need to get the depth (or range) corresponding to points in the color image.  It looks like the Spatial Mapping tool creates a mesh of triangles, with vertices in world coordinates.  I suppose I can project this mesh onto the current color image to determine the depth at every point, although I wonder if this would be slow.  It would preferable to simply get the raw data from the depth camera, in the form of an image.  It would be nice if there was a Unity wrapper that allows you to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it in Unity if you write a wrapper class and use HoloLensForCV as a winmd as in https://github.com/doughtmw/HoloLensForCV-Unity. And you can also convert the code in C# code. You need to convert the [MediaFrameSourceGroup](https://github.com/microsoft/HoloLensForCV/blob/master/Shared/HoloLensForCV/MediaFrameSourceGroup.cpp) class. The stream data is accessible via the Guids.